# Win7 pegging CPU at 100% from wuauserv - why?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

I've used Win7 as a guest with an Ubuntu host in VirtualBox for 5+ years now. Recently, either a VirtualBox update or Win7 update has caused it to peg the CPU at 100% for hours, every time I boot it.

The culprits:

```
MsMpEng.exe/MsMpSvc

Wuauserv (under svchost.exe)

TrustedInstaller.exe
```

My reading of tonnes of posts and articles tells me these are all Microsoft's and related to updates and malware scanning/detection. Not things I want to disable.

So does anyone know why these are a problem suddenly, and what should I do about it? The Win7 instance is unusable until they finish.

Comment: you may want to try clearing the windows update cache: http://coffeebreath.org/d/content/how-flush-windows-update-download-cache

Comment: provide a xperf trace of the CPU usage, so that we can see what thoe services do: http://pastebin.com/4h2ySm1V

Comment: Thanks.  I've flushed the update cache twice, no effect.

Comment: After battling with this for three weeks (I didn't post to superuser quickly), I've finally got it quiet.  I did three things - 1) ran Malware Bytes which found something spyware-like that shouldn't have been it, 2) Turned off VBox's sound, networking, and share, 3) Installed a new round of updates.  Not sure which did the trick.  If it stays quiet for a few days, I'll post more.  It usually happens after the system's been off for a few days.  Thanks for the xperf tip.  Will do.

Comment: post this as answer. TrustedInstaller.exe is called by WindowsUpdate (Wuauserv) to list all install updates, this is used to detect which updates are needed to be installed. So if you installed new updates, this is gone until next months patchday.